# Getting objects instead of object properties in array

Tags: php, object

When I set $sales like so `$sales = $response->xml->transactions` the contents look like:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [transaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [transId] => 9999999999
                    [submitTimeUTC] => 2016-03-16T21:57:54Z
                    [submitTimeLocal] => 2016-03-16T14:57:54
                    [transactionStatus] => capturedPendingSettlement
                    [invoiceNumber] => 4b1008a87f5262f0c867
                    [firstName] => Foo
                    [lastName] => Bar
                    [accountType] => Visa
                    [accountNumber] => XXXX1414
                    [settleAmount] => 155.00
                    [marketType] => eCommerce
                    [product] => Card Not Present
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [transId] =>
```

So `->transaction` contains an array.  But if I do this:

```
   $sales = $response->xml->transactions->transaction;
    foreach ($sales as $s) {
        $list[]= $s->invoiceNumber; 
    }
```

$list contains

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => ac502c094fe1722ba100
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => e2eb58351c87155e3720
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 0bca2bb6d5a13e641b67
        )
```

What am I doing wrong?  Where are the SimpleXMLElement Objects coming from where I just expected the invoiceNumber string?

Comment: I don't see `4b1008a87f5262f0c867` anywhere in the output. Maybe you used `$list` already and it had that content in it?! Initialize your array before the foreach loop `$list = [];`

Comment: you can try casting invoiceNumber: `$list[]= String($s->invoiceNumber);`

Comment: @jhonquintero - I think you mean `$list[]= (string) $s->invoiceNumber);`

Comment: Yes, I forgot how to php long time ago...

Comment: casting as string worked!  Add as answer?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) type objects is because when you are doing `$list[]= $s->invoiceNumber;` you are adding the element as it is.  Since it is part of the SimpleXMLElement object it has that type internally. This comes up a lot when working with SimpleXML so its good to keep in mind.

As mentioned in the comments [casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to a string will give you just the value:

`$list[] = (string) $s->invoiceNumber;`

Comment: Thank you.  I am waiting for the folks who gave this same answer in the comments to add their answer as selected one.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to add some additional info in case they don't come back as I used to run in to this all the time.

Comment: np, @MajicBob answer is quite complete, upvoting his one.